# Running a Java application through a desktop shortcut without opening a new window for cmd

Tags: windows-xp, java

I'm a Java newbie and I just found out that I had two installations of JRE on my system, one through the JDK and a separate JRE installation. I decided to uninstall the latter since it was redundant and after it was uninstalled I added the "...\jdk\jre\" path in the PATH environment variable. In spite of that, a Java application I've been using prompted a message that it requires JRE etc. So I changed its shortcut's target from "C:\foo\bar.exe" to "cmd /k java -jar C:\foo\bar.exe" and it runs fine with the exception that now the windows that are opened every time I run the above application are two. One for cmd and a separate one for the application (through the JRE). How can I avoid that? The only option available in the shortcut's properties is for it to be ran minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "javaw.exe" instead of "java.exe"

https://serverfault.com/questions/35116/what-is-the-difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe